# Constructing a Password in Java

Tags: java, loops

Just started teaching myself how to program java. First part is a simple mathematical equation where the user has to find the value of 'n'. There is an 'if' or 'else', if the answer is correct (21) how do I bypass the else and run the rest of the program and if 'else' how do I terminate the program after the two attempts?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class Bot {

    public static void main(String[] args) {        
        System.out.println("(6*7)%2=n");
        int InQuestion;
        System.out.println("what is the value of ' n' in the equation");
        Scanner ScannedNumber = new Scanner (System.in);
        int n = ScannedNumber.nextInt();
        InQuestion= n;

        if (InQuestion==21)
            System.out.println("Access Allowed");
            //*If 'Access Allowed' then permit the rest of the program to run consequently
            //*passing the 'else' branch.
        else
            System.out.println("try again");

        for(n=0; n>2; n++);{
            int n1=ScannedNumber.nextInt();
            if (n1==21);
                System.out.println("Access Denied");
                System.exit(0);
        }

        System.out.println("Hello I Am Bot");
        System.out.println("What is Your Name?");
        Scanner VariableNamePerry=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Hello," +VariableNamePerry.nextLine());
        Scanner VariableNamecalculate=new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.println(" What can I do for you?");
        System.out.print(VariableNamecalculate.nextLine());
        System.out.print(" what?");
        Scanner VariableNameThatIsWhatIWantYouToDo=new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.println("I Can Calculate The Square Of Any Number, If that Is What You Want?" +VariableNameThatIsWhatIWantYouToDo.nextLine());
        Scanner VariableNameOkay=new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.println(VariableNameOkay.nextLine()+ (" then"));
        System.out.println("Give me a number...");

        Scanner VariableName1=new Scanner (System.in);
        for(int MyVar=0; MyVar<1000; MyVar++){
            int MyVar1 = VariableName1.nextInt(); 
            System.out.println(MyVar1*MyVar1);
            System.out.println("give me another number please?")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Start by formatting your code cleanly; it's difficult to read.

Comment: Start by following naming and formatting conventions. Use comments. Name variables starting with lower case not upper. Name varialbes something that describes what they do not "VariableNameThatIsWhatIWantYouToDo". And you don't need a new scanner for every single line of input you want to read. You can use the same one.

Comment: @nhouser9 Code should be readable to the extent where comments aren't needed. Good naming conventions should be the only source of description you need.

Comment: I do not understand what is the relation between your code and title of your problem statement?
What you want to achieve should be briefly depicted in your title!

Comment: Try to put 2 different functionality in 2 different functions so as to make it more readable.

Comment: Okay, what is a functionality?

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to put blocks around your if and else statement to scope them. If you want to stop after two attempts, you can use a while loop or do while loop and have a simple counter count the number of attempts, and while they are wrong increment the counter.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a loop to loop through the beginning portion of the code until either the access has been granted or they have ran out of attempts. And if the access has been granted then just use some sort of indicator when breaking out of the loop.

```
int attempts = 2;
boolean accessGranted = false;
for (int q = 0; q < attempts; q++){
    System.out.println("(6*7)%2=n");
    int InQuestion;
    System.out.println("what is the value of ' n' in the equation");
    Scanner ScannedNumber = new Scanner (System.in);
    int n = ScannedNumber.nextInt();
    InQuestion= n;

    if (InQuestion==21){
        System.out.println("Access Allowed");
        accessGranted = true;
        break;
    }
    else
        System.out.println("try again");
}
if (accessGranted){/*rest of program*/}
```

Answer (score 0):

For the continuation of the program, the best way to do this is to put the actual program code in a separate void from main.

Here is an example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("(6*7)%2=n");
    int InQuestion;
    System.out.println("what is the value of ' n' in the equation");
    Scanner ScannedNumber = new Scanner (System.in);
    int n = ScannedNumber.nextInt();
    InQuestion= n;

    if (InQuestion==21){
        System.out.println("Access Allowed");
        program(args);
     //*If 'Access Allowed' then permit the rest of the program to run consequently
     //*passing the 'else' branch.
    } else {
        System.out.println("try again");
        for(n=0; n>2; n++){
            int n1=ScannedNumber.nextInt();
            if (n1==21);
            System.out.println("Access Denied");
            System.exit(0);                
        }
    }
}

public static void program(String[] args){ 
    System.out.println("Hello I Am Bot");
    System.out.println("What is Your Name?");
    Scanner VariableNamePerry=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Hello," +VariableNamePerry.nextLine());
    Scanner VariableNamecalculate=new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.println(" What can I do for you?");
    System.out.print(VariableNamecalculate.nextLine());
    System.out.print(" what?");
    Scanner VariableNameThatIsWhatIWantYouToDo=new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.println("I Can Calculate The Square Of Any Number, If that Is What You Want?" +VariableNameThatIsWhatIWantYouToDo.nextLine());
    Scanner VariableNameOkay=new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.println(VariableNameOkay.nextLine()+ (" then"));
    System.out.println("Give me a number...");

    Scanner VariableName1=new Scanner (System.in);
    for(int MyVar=0; MyVar<1000; MyVar++){
        int MyVar1 = VariableName1.nextInt(); 
        System.out.println(MyVar1*MyVar1);
        System.out.println("give me another number please?");
    }
}
```

like Nkdy said, you can use a while loop to add to an int until it reaches the specified limit.

Comment: Thanks for the help, can you give me an example of a while loop please, I am having a hard time with the logic and mostly the syntax. I also can't seem to make 'breaks' work either

Comment: @Anaphase A `while` loop is basically a stripped down `for` loop, and only takes one parameter: `while(MyVar < 1000){ DoStuff(); }` So, on a `for` loop you can make a new int and increment it within the parameters. With a `while` loop you can only specify the logic.